# pulling data from mysql to dropdown box instead of data, the no value appears

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am pulling data from mysql to the dropdownbox. This is not my first time to do this, in the edit page I have 2-3 other dropdownbox that pull data from the database, but this one behaves differently.

[image]

```
<label>User Name</label><br>
<select name="UserName" id="usernameSentakushi">
      <option value="" <?php echo($UserName==''?' selected="selected"':'');?>>--</option>
      <?php
                   $setsu = dbSetsuzoku();
                   $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `Username` FROM `playerdb`";
                   $usernameData="";
                   $result = $setsu->query($sql);
                    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                     {
                        $selected = ($UserName==$row['UserName'])?'selected="selected"':'';
                        $usernameData.='<option value="'.$row['UserName'].'"'.$selected.'>'.$row['UserName'].' - '.$row['UserName'].'</option>';
                     }
                    echo $usernameData;
                    $setsu = null;
                  ?>
      </select>
```

Comment: Show rendered html instead of a picture that does nothing to show the issue and is posted to a spammy website

Comment: show me the generated html

Comment: Show us the generated HTML/ OUTPUT of your code in the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array indexes are case sensitive...

Meaning that you are selecting `Username` but using `$row['UserName']`

Comment: Oh I see, the field on the database is UserName, i thought sql queries arent case sensitive thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is no `$row['UserName']` but you should use `$row['Username']` in options statement